# Using Radix sort to sort a list of words alphabetically in Python

Tags: python, radix-sort, alphabetical-sort

I have a list of words, 
array = ['alien', 'and', 'alien', 'aggressive', 'alien', 'creature', 'and']

However, every time i sort it, I am getting
array = ['aggressive', '**alien**', '**and**', '**and**', '**alien**', '**alien**', 'creature']
which is wrong because the "alien"s are separated by the "and"s (same words should be grouped together).

Can someone point out what is the issue with my radix sort that is giving me this problem? Thanks in advance!

```
def wordSort(word_list):
    max_len_word = find_max_char(word_list)
    radix_sort(word_list, max_len_word)

def find_max_char(word_list):
    max = 0
    for word in word_list:
        if max < len(word):
            max = len(word)
    return max

def radix_pass(array, base, digit):
    counter = [0 for i in range(base-1)]

    for i in range(1, len(array)):
        counter[get_digit(array[i], digit, True)] += 1

    position = [0 for i in range(base)]
    for value in range(base):
        position[value] = position[value-1] + counter[value-1]

    temp = [0 for i in range(len(array))]
    for i in range(len(array)):
        temp[position[get_digit(array[i], digit, True)]] = array[i]
        position[get_digit(array[i], digit, True)] += 1
    return temp

def get_digit(array_i, digit, boolean):
    if boolean == True:
        if len(array_i) - 1 < digit:
            return 0
        else:
            return ord(array_i[digit]) - 96

def radix_sort(array, digit):
    base = 27
    for i in range(digit-1, -1, -1):
        sorted_array = radix_pass(array, base, i)
    return sorted_array
```

Comment: Are you trying to recode `sorted()` ? If not you can just use it

Comment: Yea I'm trying to code it myself. Any idea why it's causing instability while sorting?